# jquery hide/show on mouse over works only for one div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have several div's floated left, and each havea CHILD DIV which should hide on mouse over. It works only for first container/parent div. for other it doesn't.

I am looking to achive, when mouseover parent DIV child div hides, on mouseout child div appears. and this shouls work for all containers/parent div's, *i am not looking for when hover any of div1 hide all div2 :). function must work for each container in part.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T7USy/10/)

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">asdsds</div>
</div>
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">asdsds</div>
</div>
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">asdsds</div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
      $('#div2').show();
      $('#div1').hover( function() { $('#div2').fadeToggle(); } );
});
```

Please help!

Comment: You have used the ID div1/div2 more than once. IDs should always be used to **uniquely** identify elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everybody has already said, id should be unique and you should definitely use classes instead. Having said that, you can "cheat" by changing the selector to include the tagname, i.e.:

```
$(function() {
      $('div#div2').show();
      $('div#div1').hover( function() {
          $(this).find('div#div2').fadeToggle();
      } );
});
```

That should work in most browsers even though your id is not unique, because it changes the underlying selection process.

Note also that you have to use `.find()` (or similar method) to only toggle the element that is a child of the currently hovered item - you'll note I'm using `$(this).find(...` within the hover handler.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/T7USy/12/

But I really don't recommend that "cheat" method, you *should* definitely change your html markup to not have the duplicate ids:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">asdsds</div>
</div>
<!-- etc -->
```

With corresponding changes in your CSS and JS:

```
  $('.div1').hover( function() {
      $(this).find('.div2').fadeToggle();
  } );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/T7USy/16/

Comment: Very, clear, nice structure, helpful, the best answer! Thank you!

Comment: You should edit this answer to simply provide the class implementation to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Use classes instead of `id`. You can only have one of any given id.

Try this:

```
<div class="div1"><div class="div2">asdsds</div></div>
<div class="div1"><div class="div2">asdsds</div></div>
<div class="div1"><div class="div2">asdsds</div></div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $('.div1').hover( function() {
          $(this).find('.div2').fadeToggle();
      } );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if i use class, it will hide all div2 on h over. http://jsfiddle.net/T7USy/11/

Comment: I added what you need.

Comment: it looks like disco effect! :) http://jsfiddle.net/T7USy/15/

Comment: The fact it was "working" for one div previously is miss-leading you. There is a flaw in this code because you are fading out elements that are floating left. Once they are gone the screen updates and the other elements will move left. You should fade in and out the inner div (div2) and leave div1 alone.

Comment: Ah I see someone has since built this answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

When using jQuery, IDs must be unique. For groups, use a class name instead.

Comment: not just jQuery. In fact most things in computing!

Comment: In HTML5 IDs don't have to be unique. Every time I open my mouth and say they need to be unique (due to the nature of the problem), I'm slapped with the HTML5 come-back.

Comment: if i use class, it will hide all div2 on h over. http://jsfiddle.net/T7USy/11/

Comment: @Diodeus - Do you have a reference for that? The html5 reference I'm looking at says ID must be unique: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id (what has changed in html5 is that it is less restrictive about what values an id can have, e.g., it can now start with a digit).

Comment: I'm going to find out the hard way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774464/multiple-identical-element-ids-in-html5-how-is-this-supposed-to-work-with-scri

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is that you duplicated ID. You should use classes for this task:

```
$('.div2').show();
$('.div1').hover(function() {
    $('.div2', this).stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

Another problem: `$('#div2').fadeToggle();`. You probably want to toggle only one div at a time, currently hovered, so you should provide a context:

```
$('.div2', this).stop().fadeToggle();
```

or

```
$(this).find('.div2').stop().fadeToggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T7USy/13/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using too many id's, but here's a way that should solve your particular problem. This uses the [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
<div id="up1">
    <div id="sub1">asdsds</div>
</div>
<div id="up2">
    <div id="sub2">asdsds</div>
</div>
<div id="up3">
    <div id="sub3">asdsds</div>
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
$(function() {
      $('[id^=sub]').show();
      $('[id^=up]').hover( function() { $('[id^=sub]').fadeToggle(); } );
});
```

This will show/hide each respective element.

Hope this helps