# Multiple identical element IDs in HTML5 - how is this supposed to work with scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've answered hundreds of jQuery questions. One of the common newbie mistakes is to use multiple element IDs, like so:

```
<div id="a">....</div>
<div id="a">....</div>
```

Then they'll do something like this and ask why it doesn't work as expected:

```
$('#a').hide();
```

I usually respond with:

> ```
> IDs must be unique
> ```

...to which someone always responds with:

> But not in HTML5!

**The question**: So if multiple identical IDs are allowed in HTML5, how are scripts supposed to handle them, or should we still be avoiding the use of multiple identical element IDs?

Comment: _multiple identical IDs are allowed in HTML5_, Where have you read this?

Comment: That's absolutely wrong ;) _HTML5 gets rid of the additional restrictions [on the id attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute). The only requirements left — **apart from being unique in the document** — are that the value must contain at least one character (can’t be empty), and that it can’t contain any space characters_

Comment: My response to _But not in HTML5_ is _So what?_. Just because it's allowed doesn't mean it makes sense to have multiples. I guess it just comes down to knowing what your DOM query is going to return instead of assuming what it will return.

Comment: Are you sure you see people saying that HTML5 allows multiple IDs? IDs have different naming rules in HTML5, and people frequently comment about that (myself included). Aren't you confused?

Comment: I've never seen someone say *"But not in HTML5"* regarding ID's being unique.

Answer (score 12):

Just quoting from [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID).
>   [DOMCORE]
>
> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's `home subtree` 
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not
>   contain any space characters.

I guess in the general sense, `ID` may be a misnomer. However, it should be valid within the subtree context.

A home subtree is:

> A node's [home subtree](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#home-subtree) is the subtree rooted at that node's root
>   element. When a node is in a Document, its home subtree is that
>   Document's tree

Comment: Ok, now define "home subtree". :P

Comment: And scripting is business as usual regarding this I guess...

Comment: Sounds like nothing has really changed, ID's still must be unique within the DOM. Dom Frags can have their own set of ID's that are duplicated on the DOM, just to their own home subtree which starts at the dom fragment, which is how it behaves anyway.

Comment: Another reason is, by mandating strict mode (as per the specs) the browsers can no longer support bad code (older versions of HTML, etc). Hence making it more friendly and try failing gracefully where possible, and mandating the specs only when absolutely required.

Answer (score 3):

I vote to avoid using multiple identical IDs.  <strike>Jquery returns an array of elements based on the selector which will hide the misuse of this convention</strike>.

When using IDs as the jquery selector only 1 element is returned: [Jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

I will continue to keep my IDs unique. It just makes development easier.